# GET SQL QUERY ONCHANGE() VIA JSCRITP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to enable the checkbox, when I select the user.

PHP:

```
  $secuencia  = "select US.usuario, US.Nombre, US.Apellido FROM  usuarios as US where US.usuario<>'52223' order by nombre ";
            $RTA = mysql_query($secuencia,$conexion);
   
        $infoexistente  = "select PA.Fotocopia_Dni, PA.Fotocopia_Partida_Nacimiento, PA.Fotocopia_Libreta_Matrimonio, PA.Fotocopia_Ketuba, PA.Solicitud_Inscripcion, PA.Requerimiento_Documentos
FROM papeles as PA
where PA.usuario'$_Post[usuario]'";
        $personal = mysql_query($infoexistente,$conexion);
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="input-icon">
    <select  class="form-control" placeholder="DNI" name="usuario" onchange="info()" required>                                                                              <option value="">Seleccione DNI</option>
    <? while($data = mysql_fetch_row($RTA)){ ?>
    <option value="<?=$data[0]?>"><?=$data[1],' ',$data[2]?></option>
    <? }?>
</select>   
    <div class="form-control-focus"> </div>
    <span class="help-block">Ingresar el DNI sin puntos ni guiones </span>
    </div>
```

I need JavaScript to update the SQL without actually doing the submit in the form.

If the entry exist in the database it should change this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="make-switch" data-on-text="&nbsp;Si&nbsp;"
data-off-text="&nbsp;No&nbsp;"  name="Documento">
```

to this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="make-switch" data-on-text="&nbsp;Si&nbsp;"
data-off-text="&nbsp;No&nbsp;"  name="Documento" CHECKED>
```

Comment: using ajax and pass data in

Comment: i don't know how to use Ajax... I spent almost two hours looking in google and nothing....

Comment: you can use ajax by jquery , it easy and short than javascript

Comment: check my answer